# Pygame "Timed Event" function

Tags: python, pygame

I've never found a clear answer to how I could create a timed event in pygame,

I want to create a timed movement with duration and cooldown. (let's say 1s and 2s respectively for this example).
Similar to an Evade or Dash skill in games

I've reedited the code and:

```
dash_now = 0
dash_cooldown = 2
    if dash:
        while dash_now < 2 and dash_cooldown >= 0:
            dash_now +- clock.tick(60) / 1000
            player.dash()
            firing == False
        else:
            dash = not dash
            dash_now ==  0
            dash_cooldown == 3
            dash_cooldown +- clock.tick(60) / 1000
```

Not working so far... I must be commiting a stupid mistake over here and I can't see which it is.

Answer (score 2):

Its actually pretty simple:

Lets say you have a timer variable

```
timer = 0
```

After that, during every iteration, you add the time that has passed since the last frame:

```
timer += my_clock.tick(60) / 1000
```

Finally, later in the code, you can check if it meets a certain threshold.

```
if timer >= 2:
    # Insert whatever you want

    timer = 0
```

Therefore your code can be greatly simplified like this, as long as youre not expecting to be in a loop for the entirety of the movement.

```
self.dash_delay = 0
self.is_dashing = 0

def dash(self):
        if dash_delay < 0 and self.is_dashing < 2:

            self.rect.x += self.speedx * 2
            self.rect.y += self.speedy * 2
            self.is_dashing +- clock.tick(60) / 1000

        elif self.is_dashing > 2:
            self.dash_delay = 3
            self.is_dashing = 0

        self.dash_delay -= clock.tick(60) / 1000
```

Comment: To add to this, since you will likely use several cooldowns, a list like `time_since_last_use` with an element in it for each ability you have would be useful.  Then, whenever you want to use ability `4`, check `if(time_right_now -time_since_last_use[4] < ability_cooldowns[4]): do ability and update time_since_last_use[4]`

Comment: Please edit your code into the question, not add it in a comment.

Comment: Care to help me with the example I proposed as an update to the question? (I did it by mistake I corrected it now)

Comment: Sadly I'll be gone for a while and cant update my code, I'll comment again when I've done so to give feedback

Comment: It did not help me at all so far so I opted to put it outside the object itself, care to check the code and perhaps fix it? (I created it for dash to be active when LSHIFT is pressed once, I just incorporated some of your code)